# C++ BigInteger like Chew Keong TAN's C# version

Tags: c++, biginteger

How can I use a BigInteger class in C++ which functions the same way as Chew Keong TAN's C# version does? (this one http://sixpack-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/SixPack/Security/Cryptography/BigInteger.cs)

Searching for hours, need a BigInteger class that works 'the same way'

Comment: DEFINE "the same way"

Comment: With having the same functions like modPow and all those functions plus the same operating overload.

Comment: How can you expect us to magically know these requirements? "the same operating overload" could mean too many things.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at [Boost Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html).

This library comes with it's own (premissively licensed) implementation, but also wraps well known existing bignum libraries like

- GMP
- MPFR